# MySQL5.6とPDOで数値列を含むデータを配列などでまとめて渡すには？

Tags: php, mysql

http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2013/12/18/pdo-prepare-statement-numeric-literal-part2/

---

**質問1**
・上記リンク先で下記のように記述していますが、例えば10カラム分のデータを渡す場合、10回$prepare->bindValue()指定しなければいけないのでしょうか？
・配列か何かでまとめて渡してもう少し簡潔に書く方法はないでしょうか？

```
 $prepare->bindValue(':id', $int, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $prepare->bindValue(':lang', $str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

**質問2**
・下記の方に(int)でキャストしている記述がありますが、これは万が一文字列型で渡されたとしても、intへ強制変換する、という意味でしょうか？
・例えば、intしか渡さないように実装しておけば、この(int)キャスト記述は不要？

```
$prepare->bindValue(':id', (int) $int, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問１ 
$prepare->bindValue() のタイピング量を減らしたいのであればこんな感じにします。 
コーディング量は増えますよ。

```
$bindArray = array(
                array('param' => ':id',   'value' => $int, 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT), 
                array('param' => ':lang', 'value' => $str, 'type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
             );

foreach ($bindArray as $bindParam){
    $prepare->bindValue($bindParam['param'], $bindParam['value'], $bindParam['type']);
}
```

質問２ 
そうです。